# (Re)Binding JQuery Mobile control state to values set in underlying markup

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I'm using JQuery Mobile 1.1.0 and I'm having trouble keeping the underlying list selections in sync with the rendered state of the JM control. Here is an example:

This is a sample of the control type being used.

```
<fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal" data-mini="true">
    <select name="taResidentYears" id="taResidentYears">
        <option selected="selected" value="">Years</option>
        <option value="0">0 Years</option>
        <option value="1">1 Year</option>
        <option value="2">2 Years</option>
    </select>
    <select name="taResidentMonths" id="taResidentMonths">
        <option selected="selected" value="">Months</option>
        <option value="0">0 Months</option>
        <option value="1">1 Month</option>
        <option value="2">2 Months</option>
    </select>
</fieldset>
```

On a normal page load the control renders properly and may then have values selected as follows...

[image]

However, on some page load scenario's I have background JQuery routines sets the value of each **select** control from data stored in local storage. In these scenario's, the JQuery Mobile rendering of this falls out of sync and I get the following even though the values are actually set. These values represent the selection-pending values.

[image]

Insofar as the underlying form is concerned, all the values are correct and nothing has been lost. Its just the visual representation that is out of sync.

What can I do to get the JM controls to re-bind to the underlying values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out I just needed to ensure I ordered the script tags such that the JQuery Mobile one was last in the list. In some cases, I needed to call the associated JQuery `Refresh()` method to rebind.